# Comparing sums of reciprocals

Tags: number-theory

Prove (or disprove) the following statement:
For any positive integers $x,y,t$,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{t(y+1)-1} \frac{1}{t(xy+x-1)-x+i}$$

is an increasing function of $t$.

My attempts:
The statement appears to be true numerically.
Tried some obvious bounds to compare the sums for consecutive values of $t$ but didn't find one that was strong enough to prove the statement.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use the fact that the $n^{th}$ [Harmonic Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)

$H_n = \ln n + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n} - O(\frac{1}{n^2})$

Your sum is a difference of two such numbers and so is approximately of the form $\ln\frac{at+b}{ct+d}$ where $a > c$.

Sorry, haven't done the complete math, but this approach looks promising.

Comment: Well hey there M :)

Comment: @BlueRaja: Hey! :-) Just discovered this one today. Finally something to get rid of my addiction to stackoverflow :-P

Comment: Hi from me too. :-) Another future addiction for you, given your answers on SO: you may want to commit on the proposal for [theoretical computer science](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8766/theoretical-computer-science?referrer=5tsJnxHB0YaB49QQOgt7xA2) (rm "referrer" part of the link if you wish).

Comment: @Shree: Hi, I never knew that existed! Thanks for pointing me to that.

Comment: @Aryabhata Welcome back! I miss pinging your old name...

Comment: @MathGems: Thanks! You can still do, I suppose :-)